# windows mfc dialog flashes on Invalidate

Tags: c++, mfc

I have a dialog based MFC app that has a lot of text edits and some other stuff.

I call Invalidate(); about 10x per second since all those text edits need updating (they are all tied to globals set in a thread)

i was expecting only the text edit field to flash a bit but the entire dialog is flashing which is not nice.

Is there a better way? UpdateData() just crashes

Comment: Changing the content of an edit control should invalidate it by-inference, so I'm not convinced you need the `Invalidate()` call *at all* (assuming you are properly allowing the message pump to do its job). And `UpdateData` crashing is a clear indication you're not doing something right in the first place.

Comment: I agree that `UpdateData` causing a crash must be fixed first!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Invalidate just redisplays the Contents when the next WM_PAINT message is genereated from the message pump.
2. If you call Invalidate on the Dialog itself the Background of the Dialog an all children are overwritten with the Background brush when you don't have WS_CLIPCHILDREN defined.

If you want to force an immediate redraw of all windows with reduced flickering define WS_CLIPCHILDREN on the dialog and use RedrawWindow with RDW_UPDATENOW RDW_ALLCHILDREN. When edit controls are changed they will be redisplayed in this moment.

But updateing controls ten times a second might not be a good way to use a UI to inform a user.

BTW: When UpdateData crashes you have a massive bug in you program. You should fix it. UpdateData doesn't cause an immediate redisplay of edit and statics.